# Test an application

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Can every one tell me about type of test in a application. I heared about TestCase, UnitTest, FunctionalTest and another type of test, but I don't know these discription and usage of these. Please help me to understanding all about Test Process in an application.

Comment: I think that you need to be a little more specific.

Comment: I just want to know about the Testing and TestMethodologies.

Comment: huuuge subject. Maybe you should split in several question ? Because with that question you will have the same result as a google search.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know about the different type of testing then find the link given below:

[Types of Testing](http://shailajakiran-testing.blogspot.com/2007/08/different-types-of-testing.html)

Comment: Thanx for your help. I'm was looking for a general list like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few links that should introduce testing for you:

- http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~michal/book/index.html
- http://cs.gmu.edu/~offutt/softwaretest/powerpoint/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing

But I agree with previous comments - it's an incredibly general question and a very broad area.

Comment: Ok thanx, I agree with you. But I need to a general guidance to start.

Comment: Ok, well check those out - the first two links are university materials on the subject.